# Construction of a ring from a category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Here is a straightforward construction I haven't seen before:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category and consider the set $\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-formal sums of elements from $\mathcal{C}$.  Define multiplication on elements $f, g \in \mathcal{C}$ by $gf = g \circ f$ if $dom(g) = cod(f)$ and $0$ otherwise.  This extends by linearity to a multiplication on $\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{C}$, making it into a non-commutative ring.

For an example, let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with $n$ elements with exactly one non-identity arrow between each pair of distinct objects.  Then $\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{C} \cong M_n(\mathbb{Z})$.

This is a small generalization of the semigroup ring construction, which includes the polynomial and matrix rings.  So, easy enough... but does this have a name?

Comment: Feel free to use another ring R besides Z here.  I choose Z to be as low-tech as possible, I want just enough to pull off the construction, nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [category algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+algebra). As you define it, it is *non-unital* if $\mathcal{C}$ has infinitely many objects. It also generalises quiver algebras.